# Is “the many” grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, determiners, noun-phrases

The homework is as following

> As it stands, our rule allows just one determiner in an NP.

```
NP → (D) (AdjP+) N (PP+) (CP) (PP+)
```

> How can we revise this rule to account for the following data:

```
...
b. the many faces
...
```

Now people in `#english` on freenode argued that *the many* is rather
forced, on the edge of acceptability. Does this hold?

Comment: They would be well-advised to stop reading freenode and start reading books. "The many faces" is unexceptionable.

Comment: The question and answer have been useful to me, shame it is closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, *the many faces* is fine; so are *the various faces*, *the few faces*, *the several faces*, *both the faces*, etc.  Your Freenode people are on the edge of wrong. See [this Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=%22the+many%22&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#client=opera&rls=en&q=%22the%20many%22&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=bks&source=og&sa=N&tab=wp&psj=1&ei=tQpqULW1K8mLyAG2l4D4Cw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=ce78f0ce165d3d65&biw=1088&bih=721) on “the many”, to discover the many sorts of *the-many* examples that exist out there.

- The many costs of racism
- The many faces of shame
- The many voices of
- The many legalities of
- The many voices of history

And many more.  But “many voices” seems the most common.

The problem is that you are assuming *many* can only be a determiner. I think you should consider that it could also be of another, more liberal class.  Then you wouldn’t have to fix your rule.

Otherwise you would have to change the rule to

```
NP → (D+) (AdjP+) N (PP+) (CP) (PP+)
```

But that would admit many invalid parses, so I don’t really suggest it.

You may have to subdivide your determiners.

Comment: And, lest we forget, *The Many Loves of Dobie Gillis*

Comment: Or the [seven faces of Dr. Lao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_Faces_of_Dr._Lao)

Comment: "Because the needs of the one outweighed the needs of the many."

Comment: @MετάEd  Isn't that D N ?